# How do I give parameters to a method?

Tags: ruby, parameters

I wrote this code:

```
def sumeven (i)
  result = 0
  while i < 100
    if i % 2 == 0
      result += i
    end
    i += 1
  end
  result
end
```

How do I give the `i` for the equation?  When I run the equation in the terminal (mac), I get no output because I'm unable to figure out how to substitute the `i` for a number. Substituting the "i" with a number in the text editor still gives no output.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def sumeven(i)
  # method implementation...
end

# call the method, passing it an argument
sumeven(4)
```

If this actually answers your question, may I suggest taking a tiny step back and reading a book on ruby before you get too much farther?  You are asking why the car doesn't go before you know how to use the gas pedal.

Comment: +1 "You are asking why the car doesn't go before you know how to use the gas pedal." Or what the key is for.

Comment: There was more the question and it explained thoroughly, but someone edited my post and deleted everything important. I've been using repl.it since I started learning Ruby and only recently (yesterday) installed Ruby on my Mac. The issue I'm running into is when I substitute "i" for any number (in the text editor), when using the mac terminal, I get this error:

MacBook-85:documents Mac$ ruby sumeven.rb
sumeven.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
def sumeven (3)
              ^
if I leave it as "i" it just gives me:
MacBook-85:documents Mac$

Getting in irb wont work either

Comment: The real answer to this to add the ARGV variable to the end of the code like so: 

        def sumeven (i)
          result = 0
          while i < 100
            if i % 2 == 0
              result += i
            end
            i += 1
          end
          result
        end

        puts sumeven(ARGV[0].to_i)

Then,in the terminal if you saved your document as sumeven.rb to run it, you would type:

        ruby sumeven.rb 10

to substitute 10 for i